# Importing txt file containing a list of data frames

Tags: r, import

Recently, I produced a txt file containing a list of data frames using the function:

```
save(..., file="name")
```

However, I'm not sure what function and arguments to use to import it. Can you help me, please? Do you think maybe I should have saved it in a different manner?

Comment: At the very top of `?save` it says: "The objects can be read back from the file at a later date by using the function load or attach (or data in some cases)". You can then click through to `load` and `attach` to see how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `load()`. Be sure to either hardcode it with `load(file="X:/path/name.txt")`,

or set your working directory first according to the folder that contains your saved file before loading:

```
setwd("X:/path/") 
load(file="name.txt")
```